# How do I deal with Memory Error in Jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the `apriori` function from `mlxtend` and I'm getting a memory error.

```py
a=apriori(data4, min_support=0.0001 , use_colnames=True)
```

This same code ran perfectly fine one week ago. I've tried restarting the kernel, getting rid of temp files, closing all other tabs in Chrome. Dataframe is approximately 7400x180 and quite sparse.

Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: If you could post more of your code it might help. What is in data4?

Comment: what os are you using? are you monitoring your memory usage from all apps? e.g. use `activity monitor` on mac os?

Comment: This was on Windows 10. I managed to solve it by turning the dataset into boolean values. Thanks, Mason and DMarczak!